# why mytheme/single-product.php works but not mytheme/woocommerce/single-product.php

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I´m making my first Woocommerce theme.
In the documentation and in `plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php`, it´s written :

> This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php

But when I do this, it does not work and if I put the file on my theme root, it got it, why ?

Comments inside files and WooCommerce documentation are not updated ?

Comment: did you add **add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );** in your theme ?

Comment: @Chetan is [correct](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes). And `single-product.php` in the *root theme folder* works because that is a valid/recognized template for single posts of the `product` type - i.e. `single-<post type>.php` - and by default, it has a higher priority and would be used even if your theme does have `woocommerce/single-product.php`.

Comment: @ChetanVaghela Thank you ! It´s exaclty what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChetanVaghela said in comments, to use the woocommerce structure you need to add this code line :

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sally in the comments above gave a very informative answer to this question, which answers the OP.

I would like to quote it again:

> `single-product.php` in the root theme folder works because that is a
> valid/recognized template for single posts of the product type - i.e.
> `single-<post type>.php` - and by default, it has a higher priority
> and would be used even if your theme does have
> `woocommerce/single-product.php`

Also Chetan mentioned to add theme support with

```php
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

But note, if at `woocommerce.php` file resides a your your theme's root folder, the `single-product.php` and `archive-product.php` wont work.

WooCommerce plugin comes with a handy checking tool at your Dashboard. Go the WooCommerce -> Status

- And it reports if your theme has been modified to add wocommerce support or not.
- Any flags to notice
- And at the last section it shows the list of template files which are overwritten and if there are issues regarding them. For example, if your theme has a `woocommerce.php` it would notify you it too!

[image]